# Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException:

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Error: Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing
com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTask$ParseResourcesRunnable

---

Wow, This is my first Stackoverflow question as a programmer.
The problem I'm getting is in Android ( Java ) when running the project
tried many things but not got any solution. Please help.

Comment: question titles are typically in the format of a question, you need to include enough information here for others to recreate the problem. when does this occur ? does this have something to do with your gradle dependencies ? please include more details

Answer (score 0):

I just had the problem, just need to update all dependencies in `build.gradle(:app)` folder :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg7OP.png

When the dependencies are not up to date, they are highlighted, you hover your mouse over them and it prompts you to update them :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhnU0.png

Answer (score 0):

can be caused of
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was in the `data_extraction_rules.xml` file.  I deleted the  `TODO` but also deleted the `<!--` which was on the same line.  After re-adding `<!--` this resolved the error.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading compileSdkVersion from 30 to 31 solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

for me it just said not to include "<" character in the textview. Changed that and it was fine. Might help someone.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error for using '<' character in the value for the attribute "android:text" associated with an element type "TextView".

Try:

```
1. Build/Clean Project
2. Build/Rebuild Project
```

Comment: Had the sane isseu. Any idea why a '<' cause parsing to fail? See no warning from android studio.